# Jquery y JSON - No logro mostrar los datos

Tags: jquery, json

Estoy aprendiendo jquery y tratando de entender Json.

Tengo una página llamada **index.php** donde al cargar, se genera por php una consulta de todos los productos, dinámicamente me arma una cantidad de `divs` (.cajas) y me los muestra.

El tema es que agregué un `select` para que posterior a esa primera vista, se pueda filtrar por categoría de producto.

Por `jquery` obtengo el `change` del `select` y ocurre algo inesperado:

1. Se arman todas la cajas que se pueden ver en pantalla *(no coincide con la cantidad de registros)*, se quedan en blanco por 2 segundos y luego se completan todas con datos del primer registro.
2. Si hago un `console.table(response);`, me arroja los registros correctos en consola, incluse puse un `alert($.trim(value.id));` al final del `.each` y me muestra los id de registro correctos.
3. La idea es borrar el `DIV`, y volverlo a crear dinámicamente desde jquery con los datos filtrados por categoría.

Pongo las partes que creo más importantes, si hace falta lo cuelgo de un pastebin, no es mucho código pero son 3 archivos:

**index.php**

```
<?php
     session_start();
?>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <link href="css/estilo.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <script src="jquery-3.1.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <script>
            var getdetailsfilter = function(categoria) {
                return $.getJSON("busca_articulos.php", {
                    "categoria": categoria
                });
            };

            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#combo_categorias').unbind('change').bind('change', function(e) {
                    optionSeleccionado = $(this).val();
                    alert(optionSeleccionado);
                    // Borro las cajas
                    fila = '';
                    $('.caja').empty();
                    getdetailsfilter(optionSeleccionado).done(function(response) {
                        console.table(response);
                        fila += $.each(response.data.arts1, function(key, value) {
                            $('.caja').append("<div class='caja_imagen'><img src=" + $.trim(value.imagen) + " style=widht='100' height='100' /><p class='caja_nombre'>" + $.trim(value.nombre) + "</p><p class='caja_precio'>$ " + $.trim(value.precio) + "</p></div><div class='caja_boton'><form action='detalle.php' method='POST' name='detalle'><input name='id' type='hidden' value=" + $.trim(value.id) + " /><input class='boton_detalle' type='submit' value='Detalle'></form></div></div>");
                            alert($.trim(value.id));
                        });
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
```

Archivo **PHP busca_articulos.php**

```
$jsondata = array();
$cad = "SELECT * FROM `productos` WHERE `categoria` LIKE '%{$categoria}%' Order by `nombre`;";

if ($result = $con - > query($cad)) {
    if ($result - > num_rows > 0) {
        $jsondata["success"] = true;
        $jsondata["data"]["message"] = sprintf("Se ha encontrado %d coincidencia", $result - > num_rows);
        $jsondata["data"]["arts1"] = array();

        while ($row = $result - > fetch_object()) {
            $jsondata["data"]["arts1"][] = array("id" => $row - > id, "imagen" => $row - > imagen, "nombre" => $row - > nombre, "descripcion" => $row - > descripcion, "costo" => $row - > costo, "precio" => $row - > precio, "stock" => $row - > stock, "categoria" => $row - > categoria);
        }
    } else {
        $jsondata["success"] = false;
        $jsondata["data"] = array(
            'message' => 'No se encontró ningún resultado.'
        );
    }
} else {
    $jsondata["success"] = false;
    $jsondata["data"] = array(
        'message' => $database - > error
    );
}
header('Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
echo json_encode($jsondata, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
$con - > close();
}
exit();
```

Comment: Te recomiendo crear un pastebin con un ejemplo funcional para que otros usuarios puedan ayudarte. Puede que tu pregunta sea clara, pero un ejemplo funcional siempre es bueno.

Comment: A simple vista parece tener un error de promesa asincronica. Prueba moviendo dentro de la función `.done(function` las lineas `fila = '';  $('.caja').empty();`.

Answer (score 1):

La razón por la que se queda todo blanco por X cantidad de segundos es porque estas *limpiando* la caja antes de tener los resultados. Prueba cambiar tu código a esto:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var getdetailsfilter = function(categoria) {
        return $.getJSON("busca_articulos.php", {
            "categoria": categoria
        });
    };

    $('#combo_categorias').on('change', function(e) {

        getdetailsfilter($(this).val())
            .done(function(response) {
                var html = ''; // Acumulador

                $.each(response.data.arts1, function(key, value) {
                    html += "<div class='caja_imagen'><img src=" + $.trim(value.imagen) + " style=widht='100' height='100' /><p class='caja_nombre'>" + $.trim(value.nombre) + "</p><p class='caja_precio'>$ " + $.trim(value.precio) + "</p></div><div class='caja_boton'><form action='detalle.php' method='POST' name='detalle'><input name='id' type='hidden' value=" + $.trim(value.id) + " /><input class='boton_detalle' type='submit' value='Detalle'></form></div></div>";
                });

                $('#caja').html(html); // Sobre escribir el contenido HTML de <div id="caja"
            });
    });
});
```

Comment: Gracias Marcos, estoy desde esta mañana con esto ... y lo pude resolver hace un rato .. está muy bien tu comentario, de hecho voy a incorporarlo. El problema principal era que estoy limpiando .caja  , y lo que tenía que limpiar es el contenedor de .caja  que se llama productos , y luego crear las .caja nuevas ahi dentro.

Comment: Se me fue el enter jaja . Gracias !!
Aprovecho y te hago una consulta

Comment: En realidad hice una especie de carrito de compras online integramente en php, y luego me puse a estudiar jquery ajax json , lo cual me cuesta un poco pero va .. y ahora estoy mejorando cosas . 
Cuando entro a la pagina se muestran todos los productos, y en otro div mas abajo tengo la paginacion de los mismos, echa en php.

Comment: Esto nuevo que agregué es para mostrar productos por categoria, el tema es que los muestro por jquery, y la paginacion la armé en PHP , podría hacer una funcion PHP con la paginación, se te ocurre alguna forma de llamar a esa funcion tras el change del combo, o deberé migrarla a jquery ? Gracias !!

Comment: Existen muchas formas de hacer no solo la paginación sino también la búsqueda. Para este caso, dado que ya tenes las funciones para buscar y paginar hechas en PHP, se me ocurre que podrías usar la técnica que se conoce como **"server rendering"**. Generar todo el HTML del lado de servidor y devolverlo. Luegoe con JS, meter todo ese HTML en el la caja contenedora. Esta técnica tiene sus pros y contras.Mas info: http://openmymind.net/2012/5/30/Client-Side-vs-Server-Side-Rendering/